# setId() and getId() on custom listView item giving unexpected result

Tags: android-listview

I have created custom listview in which i have

`textView,imageView`.

I want to **set id** to the **each row's imageView** so that when i click on that image,can get the id(for the purpose of uniqueness).I have also a click listener in getView.So I want to get that id on click of that particular image but when i click on that image everytime i am getting 3,I don't no why this is happening.Any help would be appreciable.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final CruunNotificationModel cruun = userDetails.get(position);

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.imagewithlist, parent,
                false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.userName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.userNameTextView);
        holder.userTask = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.userTaskTextView);
        holder.dateTime = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.dateTimeTextView);
        holder.userComments = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.userCommentsTextView);
        holder.userImage = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.userImageImageView);
        holder.expandImage = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.expandTextImageView);
        holder.commentPart = (LinearLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.commentlayout);
        holder.view = (View) convertView.findViewById(R.id.view);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    holder.userComments.setText(cruun.getComments());
    holder.userName.setText(cruun.getUserName());
    holder.userTask.setText(cruun.getUserTask());
    holder.dateTime.setText(cruun.getDateAndTime());
    holder.userImage.setImageResource(cruun.getImageId());
    holder.expandImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.down_arrow);
    holder.expandImage.setId(position);
    holder.expandImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            holder.userComments.setEllipsize(null);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lParams.setMargins(2, 10, 2, 0);
            holder.userComments.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            lParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.userImageLayout);
            holder.userComments.setLayoutParams(lParams);
            holder.expandImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.up_arrow);
            notifyDataSetChanged();

            if (v.getId() == holder.expandImage.getId()) {
                holder.view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.commentPart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: why are you not used as a position in unique identifier.

Comment: I want to make changes for that particular item(imageview) not for the list view .I m not working on clicking listview,so that I am proving them a unique id to imageview.